# Phone number format

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a table field 'Phone number', the data in table is imported through a excel file link in database. The data type of the field is text since we are not sure how user enters his phone number(sometime with country code and sometime without country code).

I want to format the 'phone number' field once the table is updated everytime or data is imported into table. Format [countrycode]-[localcode]-[phone num].

I am not sure how to go about it, whether to create an update query or VBA code to update this field. Will appriciate any help in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally recommended that in database fields, the phone number is maintained in numerical format only (meaning no parenthesis, dashes, or whatnot) because it provides more stability for the data and allows for better/easier future formatting when outputting. The most recommended method is to take the number given to you and strip it of all non-numeric characters and then store that value.

If you are working with an excel sheet containing this information before it is put into the database, then you can simply format the column that contains the phone numbers to convert everything into a single numerical value so 800-555-1212 or (888) 222-1515 would just become 8005551212 and 8882221515. This can be done using the existing cell formatting option built into Excel or if you want it done on the fly a simple VBA code that triggers when the field has a value would do the trick too.

**EDIT #1** (super simple function)

```
Public Function numOnly(sToClean As String) As String
    Const NUM_CHARS = "0123456789"
    Dim lChar As Long
    Dim sResult As String
    For lChar = 1 To Len(sToClean)
        If InStr(1, NUM_CHARS, Mid$(sToClean, lChar, 1)) > 0 Then
            'Found a numeric character
            sResult = sResult + Mid$(sToClean, lChar, 1)
        End If
    Next
    'Return the result
    numOnly = sResult
End Function
```

**EDIT #2** (more feature advanced version)

```
Option Explicit 

Public Function stripChars(CheckStr As String, Optional KillNums As Boolean = False, Optional AllowedChars As String, Optional NotAllowed As String) 

     ' CheckStr = the string being evaluated
     ' KillNums [True/False] = remove numbers/remove non-numeric
     ' AllowedChars = what to allow even if you are removing non-numeric (aka KillNums=False) [ex. "$,."] or removing numbers (aka KillNums=True) [ex. "6,9"]
     ' NotAllowed = override characters never allowed and processed before any other option (meaning if you have it in both allow/not allow - not allow takes precedence
     ' NOTE: AllowedChars and NotAllowed arguments are *not* case-sensitive

    Dim Counter As Long 
    Dim TestChar As String 
    Dim TestAsc As Long 

     ' Loop through characters
    For Counter = 1 To Len(CheckStr) 
         ' Get current character and its ANSI number
        TestChar = Mid(CheckStr, Counter, 1) 
        TestAsc = Asc(TestChar) 

         ' Test first to see if current character is never allowed
        If InStr(1, NotAllowed, TestChar, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 
             ' do nothing

             ' If current character is in AllowedChars, keep it
        ElseIf InStr(1, AllowedChars, TestChar, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 
            stripChars = stripChars & TestChar 

             ' If KillNums=True, test for not being in numeric range for ANSI
        ElseIf KillNums Then 'only allow non-numbers
            If TestAsc < 48 Or TestAsc > 57 Then 
                stripChars = stripChars & TestChar 
            End If 

             ' If KillNums=False, test for being in numeric ANSI range
        Else 'only allow numbers
            If TestAsc >= 48 And TestAsc <= 57 Then 
                stripChars = stripChars & TestChar 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next 

End Function
```

You can drop either of these in your Excel's module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) or in your Access forms or what not, good luck.

Comment: Sure, I will give you two, one really simple and one with more options.

Comment: Great, I am glad to hear it.